# ¿Por qué onItemClick de gridView no funciona correctamente?

Tags: java, android, gridview, click

> Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego de preguntas con un adaptador personalizado y GridView.
>
> Por alguna razón, cuando se realiza un clic en un elemento de gridView, la vista, la posición y la identificación devuelven 0 o nulo.
>
> La aplicación se bloquea cuando intenta establecer el color de fondo del elemento.

---

> El Logcat me vincula a estas 2 líneas:

gridRespuestas.performItemClick(gridRespuestas.getChildAt(0), 0,         gridRespuestas.getItemIdAtPosition(0));

&

```java
LinearLayout respuesta = (LinearLayout) view;
respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e3535"));
```

---

> Aquí está el listener del ridView:

```
 gridRespuestas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                contador.cancel();

                gridRespuestas.setEnabled(false);
                LinearLayout respuesta = (LinearLayout) view;

                // Si la respuesta seleccionada es correcta
                boolean repuestaCorrecta = preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getRespuestas().get(position).isEsCorrecta();

                if(repuestaCorrecta ){

                    // Pone el fondo de la respuesta en verde
                    respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#355e4e"));
                }
                // Si es incorrecta
                else{
                    // Pone el fondo de la respuesta pulsada en rojo
                    respuesta.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5e3535"));

                    // Por cada view dentro de la gridview
                    GridView grid = (GridView) parent;
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < grid.getChildCount() ; i++){

                        // Coge cada elemento dentro de parent > LinearLayout > Textview
                        TextView text = (TextView)((LinearLayout)grid.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0);

                        // Si la pregunta es correcta
                        if(preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getRespuestas().get(i).isEsCorrecta()){

                            // Cambia el fondo de color verde
                            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#355e4e"));
                        }
                    }
                }

                juego(position , juegoLayout, gridRespuestas, contador);

            }
        });
```

---

> El adaptador:

```java
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Respuesta> respuestas;
    private Activity context;

    public Adaptador(Activity _context,List<Respuesta> _respuestas) {

        context = _context;
        respuestas = _respuestas;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.place_respuesta, null);
        }

        final TextView respuesta = view.findViewById(R.id.placeRespuesta);
        respuesta.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int retorno = 0;

        if(respuestas != null)
            retorno = respuestas.size();

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


}
```

---

> Logcat :

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.joc.Juego$3.onItemClick(Juego.java:136)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
        at com.example.joc.Juego$1.onFinish(Juego.java:82)
```